# Compute intersection / union of two rotated ellipses?

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, object-detection

I see a number of posts on SE and elsewhere for computing the intersection & union of two rectangles, but I've got two arbitrary ellipses: rotated, translated, different semimajor & semiminor axes.

Does anyone have a suggestion for computing their intersection-over-union value?

I'm using OpenCV & Python, for what it's worth.

If I/we can't come up with anything clever and fast, then I'll use a mask-based method whereby I just define an array of zeros, fill it in with 1's over the area defined by the first ellipse, and add 1's for the second ellipse, and then I'll know that the union is wherever the array is nonzero, and the intersection will be wherever the array is 2.  But that sounds kind of slow.

**EDIT:** Re. "Sounds kind of slow": As in, I want to evaluate this 'jillions' of times a second, so I'd prefer an analytic equation to compute this (e.g., like there is for non-rotated rectangles), rather than just a pixel-based mask implementation.

Comment: I don't really see how you could do faster than your plan. The only thing I can think of is that you don't need to compute the masks over the entire image but just in the rectangles where the ellipses are bound... And I'd go with boolean masks / logic rather than using 0,1,2 values.

Comment: you should probably go with that method, but if you want you can overload the `__and__` and `__or__` operators so you can use `&` and `|`

Comment: @0TTT0 `&` and `|` already work for boolean masks...

Comment: considering only the bounding rect areas of both ellipses (and maybe even only their union/intersection) is a good idea from @Julien

Comment: My ellipse class represents ellipses with their bounding boxes. Unions and intersections of ellipses aren't ellipses themselves so can't be represented as an ellipse. A mask of pixels/coordinates would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to make additional mask, you have to implement boolean function if in ellipse (with general ellipse equation usage):

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/434482/

And then you could color pixel only if equation is satisfied. Below I attached c++ example (i should be easy to convert it to python):

```
bool ifInEllipse(cv::Size _axes, float _angle, cv::Point _center, cv::Point _point)
{

_angle =CV_PI/180*_angle;


float cosine = cos(_angle);
float sine = sin(_angle);


float res1 = (_point.x - _center.x)*cosine + (_point.y - _center.y)*sine;
res1 = res1*res1;
float res2 = (_point.x - _center.x)*sine - (_point.y - _center.y)*cosine;
res2 = res2*res2;

float a = _axes.width;
float b = _axes.height;
return ((res1 / (a*a)) + (res2 / (b*b))) < 1;
}
```

And examplary usage:

```
cv::Mat A1,A2, B1,B2, AA,BB;
A1 = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
A2 = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);

cv::Point center1(200, 200);
cv::Size axes1(100, 50);
float angle1 =30;

cv::ellipse(A1, center1, axes1, angle1, 0, 360,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),-1);


B1 = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
B2 = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<500;j++)
    {
        if(ifInEllipse(axes1,angle1,center1,cv::Point(i,j)))
        {
            B1.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
        }
    }
}

cv::Point center2(350, 300);
cv::Size axes2(60, 120);
float angle2 = -45; 


cv::ellipse(A2, center2, axes2, angle2, 0, 360, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);


B2 = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i<500; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<500; j++)
    {
        if (ifInEllipse(axes2, angle2, center2, cv::Point(i, j)))
        {
            B2.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
        }
    }
}


AA = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);
BB = cv::Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC1);

cv::bitwise_and(A1, A2,AA);



for (int i = 0; i<500; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<500; j++)
    {
        if (ifInEllipse(axes1, angle1, center1, cv::Point(i, j)))
        {
            if (ifInEllipse(axes2, angle2, center2, cv::Point(i, j)))
            {
                BB.at<uchar>(j, i) = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]